# redirect private page to login first then display page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, private

I have several Private pages that linked from my public pages. By default when a non-logged in user clicks on one of these links they get a a 404 page. I'd like for them to get a login page and then continue on to the page they requested.

Pete's Redirect plugin is great but it wants to go to specifically designated pages per user/role after login. I'd like to just continue on to the page they requested.

Any suggestions?
thanks,
rich

Comment: How they get a 404 page ? Do you use a plugin for that like Advanced Access Manager or UAM?

Answer (score 9):

This is the right way to do

```
add_action('wp', 'redirect_private_page_to_login');

function redirect_private_page_to_login(){

    global $wp_query;

    $queried_object = get_queried_object();

    if ($queried_object->post_status == "private" && !is_user_logged_in()) {

        wp_redirect(home_url('/login?redirect='.get_permalink($queried_object->ID)));

    } 
}
```

Comment: where shall i add this code to? e.g. functions.php or page.php?

Comment: Very straightforward. If you want to redirect to the standard WP login, you'd use this instead: `wp_redirect( wp_login_url( get_permalink( $queried_object->ID ) ) );`

Answer (score 3):

I had a few problems with Tu Bui's answer. Here is an improved version.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'redirect_private_page_to_login' );
function redirect_private_page_to_login(){
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    if (
        isset( $queried_object->post_status ) &&
        'private' === $queried_object->post_status &&
        ! is_user_logged_in()
    ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_url( get_permalink( $queried_object->ID ) ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Here is the same code in a small plugin: https://github.com/wearerequired/private-page-login

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
echo '<a href="link to pvt page"> pvt page </a>';
} else{
echo '<a href="link to Login page"> login to continue </a>';
}
```

Comment: This is a great start but I was hoping for something automatic. I don't wan to have to put this code on every private page I create. Is there an automagical way?

Comment: place this code in a function and add this function to each page